# How can I constantly check that a python script is running 24/7 and is not down?

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script which has to run 24/7 on a Linux server. What's a wise way to ensure it's up?

They suggested me  to use cron and the 2nd another script which checks the 1st one somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/index.html) to do that. Cron's fine for starting it once, and keeping it running (use @reboot), but you need something a little less basic to keep an eye on things.

My config files are per application (and in ubuntu something like /etc/supervisord/conf.d/foo.conf)

This is my ttrss update script file but its a good starting point.

```
command=php ./update_daemon2.php
directory=/var/www/lupinenet/ttrss
autostart=true
startretries=5
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/ttrss/ttrss.err.log
user=www-data
```

Line by line,

first line's the command I want to run (place the command you want to run here)
The second is the directory its in (which makes it neater, in my case its running inside my web server root)
It'll autostart and try 5 times.
I want the output in case something goes wrong, so I set a file for stderr_logfile - this is optional, and set the user I want to run the task as.  I need to logrotate this but I keep forgetting ;p

You can tweak this to taste as per the [docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html)

Comment: I mean, use cron to run the 2nd script which checks the 1st one.

Comment: and what makes sure that runs correctly ;). And your 1st script won't be checked until the second cronjob runs. Supervisord takes care of most of the complexity.

Comment: **and what makes sure that runs correctly ;)** -- that's what I'm asking about, how to utilize the 2nd script and cron?

Comment: **supervisord** is overcomplicated, that's not what I want to use for sure. I could've used another web service for that and it'll work just fine, but why? why does it have to be so complex? The same goes for supervisorlord.

Comment: Writing a bash script to monitor another script is overcomplicated. Using appropriate tools for a job means one less thing to maintain, and since this is a commonly used application, bugs get fixed. I've seen supervisord keep dozens of *buggy crashy* scripts up enough that end users didn't notice. Its hardly overcomplicated. I suppose you could use a modern init system as an alternative, but cron isn't the right tool for this at all.

Comment: where did you get bash script? I'm talking about python. why do you think cron isn't the right tool? it'd run my 2nd python script once in 5 minutes and the 2nd script will check whether or not 1st python script is up.

Comment: Substitute python with bash in the above comment then. Cron is designed to *schedule* tasks. Its not really designed to do more than that. Modern init systems do support keeping something up (upstart has a respawn stanza, and I will eat my shoes without ketchup if systemd did not) I suppose, but that's not mentioned in the question. In any case *writing* a python script to do this might skirt the scope of the site. Meh. I suppose someone else can post the answer you *want*, but I'm pretty sure this is the smarter way to do it.

Comment: and cron will schedule a task which will be to run my 2nd python script.

Comment: @AlanCoromano who watches your watchdog script? Just do the *right* thing and use an init system, that's what they are made for: I suggest systemd, your distro probably already comes with it.

Comment: nothing and why would anything have to watch it?

Comment: @AlanCoromano because your watchdog script may crash as well, for example, in an OOM scenario. Dirty hacks are not robust solutions.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Systemd pretty much makes supervisor obsolete. It does all of this and more. And there's no danger of _it_ running out of memory...

Comment: Mentioned in the comments, though I didn't post an answer using systemd cause I'm not familiar with it yet, and I have this running at the moment with fairly good reliability. Nonetheless, quite a few options exist that beat cron and dogfooding;p